# Paramiko starts a SSH proccess and it dies..why?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Below is my code.  When log into the server and I run ps aux | grep python I see all of the process start and then die after a second or two.  If I run the command in the server..it works.  I have tried with nohup.whithout nohup etc  I am out of an explanation.  This is a long process that should take hours.

```
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(rsa_private_key)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname,port,username=username,pkey=key)
#stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('tar -xf /home/ubuntu/opt.tar.gz')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
#stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(bash)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('export DISPLAY=localhost:0')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('nohup python /home/ubuntu/Optimization/pvServer2.py &')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('nohup python /home/ubuntu/Optimization/pvServer2.py &')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('nohup python /home/ubuntu/Optimization/pvServer2.py &')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python /home/ubuntu/Optimization/pvServer2.py &')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python /home/ubuntu/Optimization/pvServer2.py &')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python /home/ubuntu/Optimization/pvServer2.py &')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python /home/ubuntu/Optimization/pvServer2.py &')
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Does it stay alive if you don't put the `&` (if you don't exit out of paramiko)?

Comment: Nope...tried...leaving the & did not help.  I need to close the ssh conn.

Comment: The & will not have any affect as the "&" notation it handled by shells, such as sh, or bash, which will not be used here.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the output of the command. There may be an error been written, and you won't see it with your current code. Try doing:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python /home/ubuntu/Optimization/pvServer2.py')
print 'exit_code: %d' % stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
print stdout.read()
print stderr.read()
```

Once you have figured out what is wrong, and fixed it, then you can return to using nohup.

I think what is wrong is the way you are calling the export DISPLAY command. This won't affect the env of the other commands you are running. You need to do something like this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sh -c "export DISPLAY=localhost:0; python /home/ubuntu/Optimization/pvServer2.py"')
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  When I run the code..the process is executed on the server but the ssh code just keeps on running.  I have to fore quit the app but at least the process keeps running on the server.  Nothing was printed out in the std err and output.

Comment: Could it be that I am executing a twisted function and starting a reactor?  the app is supposed to run till I kill the ec2 instance

Comment: I did a simple test.  Created a file with two lines. While True: x=2 and run forever.  Yup it runs.  I am suspecting that this has so something to do with twisted.